# how to do to wait to load ViewController until appdelegate func application will be completed

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know which is the best way to do the next:

In my `AppDelegate.swift` file I had the entry point of the app, register the instance, but before the instance is registered, the main function(inside `viewDidLoad()`) of the `MainViewController` is called and I would like to know how to do to wait the `MainViewController` `viewDidLoad()` function until the instance register will be completed.

Comment: What do you like to do during that time before loading your viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 2):

You should add extra view controller and show that view controller initially until your required task got completed. You can show loader or activity indicator or some ui that shows like getting data or etc. After you completed your process move to main viewcontroller so your viewDidload will be called when you want!

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidLoad is Async by design, so is a non-sense waiting for it.
When called you are certain UI is up, it was written for this scope.
I think is better you read carefully iOS event loop and app lifecycle, to fully undestand Apple design.

Answer (score -6):

You can use sleep()  function for wait to load viewcontrollers view

Comment: no, for some reasons:
- it makes ALL app unresponsive
- it ha s been ideated for server/workstations

Comment: No no no! This is a horrible idea, and won't solve the OPs problem.